# mongod no inicia en centOS7

Tags: linux, mongodb, mongod

Hace 20 dias migre mi base de datos mongo de la version 2.6 a la version 3.4 y ahora estoy intentando ejecutar el comando **mongod** en el sistema operativo centos7 y obtengo la respuesta de error:

**Fatal assertion 18523 InvalidOptions: The field 'uuid'**

Version de mongoDB 3.4
sistema operativo Centos7

el comando que estamos urtilizando es mongod.
Para solucioanr ¿es necesario realizar un downgrade a la version 2.6 o es posible ejecutar mongo en esta version con alguna configuraciíon adicional?

Este es el archivo mongo.conf

```
`# mongod.conf`
#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
logappend=true

`# fork and run in background`
fork=true
port=30003
dbpath=/var/lib/mongo

`# location of pidfile
pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
`# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
`#bind_ip=209.133.210.252,127.0.0.1,74.50.108.210,209.133.193.90
`# Disables write-ahead journaling
`# nojournal=true
`# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
`#cpu=true
`# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
`# noauth=true
auth=true

`# Verbose logging output.
`#verbose=true
`# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
`# developing drivers)
`#objcheck=true
`# Enable db quota management
`#quota=true

`# Set oplogging level where n is
`#   0=off (default)
`#   1=W
`#   2=R
`#   3=both
`#   7=W+some reads
`#diaglog=0

`# Ignore query hints
`#nohints=true
`# Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).
httpinterface=true
`# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
`# functionality
`#noscripting=true
`#Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
`#notablescan=true`
```

Comment: ¿Podrías verificar que tu archivo `mongod.conf` cumple con el formato que se establece en la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/configuration-options/)?

Comment: El mismo problema me esta ocurriendo con mongo 5 en centos 8